# Why not define outer measure as the infimum of sum of "length" of finite collection of open intervals?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $I$ be a nonempty open interval, its length, the difference of end points, $l(I)$. For a set $A$, its outer measure is unusually defined as:$$m^*(A) = \inf\{{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{l(I_k):A \subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}I_k}\}}$$

My question is:
Is it equivalent to define $$m^*(A) = \inf_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\{{\sum_{k=1}^{n}{l(I_k):A \subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^{n}I_k}\}}$$

Comment: Under your second definition, every unbounded set has infinite outer measure.

Comment: @NateEldredge:I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We know that the usually definition gives $m(\mathbb{Q})=0$, but to cover it with only finitely many intervals forces at least one of the intervals to have infinite length so the second definition would give $m^*(\mathbb{Q})=\infty.$